# Notification of Activity from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Within an AsyncTask, I am making a REST call to retrieve data. Within that AsyncTask, I may encounter an exception which I would like to package up (the HTTP code) and inform the Activity, which based on the HTTP response code (Timeout, Unauthorized, etc), would display different messages to the user.

What would be the best way to bubble that information up to the Activity for processing?

I have looked at a number of different Android mechanisms such as Notification, Handler, etc but I can't seem to determine a good architectural pattern for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If the error causes a halt in the users workflow, then you need to obtrusively interrupt using a dialog alert and then direct the user to the fix.  If the error does not stop the user, then interrupt unobtrusively using a toast or notification.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to have the alert created on the main UI Activity.  The AsyncTask would have to inform the Activity that an error occurred and what the error was. So you are saying to create a Notification in the AsyncTask that would inform the Activity of the error?

Comment: Is your AsyncTask an inner class of the Activity?  You can set the thrown exception to a member variable, do publishProgress, and then check for the exception in onProgressUpdate and do your notification there.